# How in Linq to entity replace true or false with On or Off?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

I need to bind grid with linq to entity(asp C#), when Im binding I need to replace true or false with On or Off. how I can accomplish it?

ex.

```
var t = from k in entity.table select k.IsActive;
```

so in result if

IsActive == true I need to return On 
IsActive == false I need to return Off

Comment: "On" and "Off" seem like a representation of the `IsAlive` field. Therfore, this seems like an presentation layer problem. Try to solve this in the GridView and not in LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 4):

```
var t = from k in entity.table select k.IsActive ? "On" : "Off";
```

Comment: Yeap, assuming IsActive is not nullable!

Comment: Well, OP doesn't say it's nullable, so I don't assume it's nullable. :P

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
var t = from k in entity.table select (k.IsActive ? On : Off);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var t = from k in entity.table select k.IsActive.GetValueOrDefault() ? "On" : "Off";
```